# Windows Update does not display update notifications (Windows 7)

Tags: windows-7, windows, security, windows-update, updates

After performing a significant amount of research and reading posts on other sites, I have concluded that many Windows 7 systems are not displaying Windows Update notifications when updates become available.

The issue occurs when Windows Update is configured to ***"Check for updates but let me choose whether to download and install them."***  For those trying to avoid Microsoft marketing "updates" promoting Windows 10, this is the only reasonable option currently available.

Unfortunately, for many systems, Windows Update is **no longer alerting the user when updates are available.**

How can Windows Update be fixed to show notifications when updates are available?

*Note that [Windows Update Notifier](https://wun.codeplex.com/) is a third-party workaround, but I am interested in learning how to fix Windows Update when it displays this symptom.*

Comment: It only notifies After they are downloaded, try the "download updates but let me choose whether to install them" setting.

Comment: @Moab The "Check for updates but let me choose whether to download and install them." is supposed to provide notifications when updates are available, before they have been downloaded.

Comment: All I can say is try the other setting.